# Ball in boxes with different probabilities

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I have 3 boxes A,B,C and $n$ balls. I put a ball in the box A with probability $p_A$, in the box B with probability $p_B$, and in the box C with probability $1-p_A-p_B$. I put all the $n$ balls independently.

I fix $m\leq n$ and I want to compute the probability that there are strictly less than $m$ balls in the first box but at least $m$ balls in the first two boxes.

I cannot find a nice expression for this probability. I just find very nasty summations. A bit of help?

Comment: What have you tried so far? What do your nasty summations look like?

Comment: If $X,Y,Z$ are random variables giving the numbers of balls in A,B,C respectively, then the complementary events are $X\geq m$ and $Z>n-m$.  These events are mutually exclusive.  I don't see any way to get expressions without summations for them, but they're simpler than the double summation I get by computing the probability directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Distribution is multinomial:
$$P(x_1,x_2,x_3,n)=\frac{n!}{x_1!x_2!x_3!}p_1^{x_1}p_2^{x_2}p_3^{x_3}, \ \ \ \  p_1+p_2+p_3=1, \ \ \ \  x_1+x_2+x_3=n$$
The probability we are interested in is
$$P(\{X_1<m\}\cap\{X_1+X_2 \geq m\})=P(\{X_1 < m\}\cap \{X_3 \leq n-m\})
$$
So
$$P(\{X_3 \leq n-m\}\cap \{X_1 < m\})=\sum_{x_1=0}^{m-1}P(\{X_3 \leq n-m\}\cap \{X_1 = x_1\})=$$
$$=\sum_{x_1=0}^{m-1}\sum_{x_3=0}^{n-m}P(x_1,n-x_1-x_3,x_3,n)$$